# Property Binding not working with UserControl with inheritance

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Im trying to bind a property of a `Page` to a customized `Slider` control (TwoWay) which inherits directly from the `Slider`.
It doesnt't seem to work though, a direct binding from a `TextBlock` works just fine, but not when working with the property in my `Page`

**Demo-Code (excerpts)**

**`Page`Code**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private double _slidervalue;

    public double SliderValue
    {
        get { return _slidervalue; }
        set
        {
            this._slidervalue = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SliderValue)));
        }
    }
```

**XAML in my `Page`**

```
<!-- doesnt work -->
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl" Value="{Binding SliderValue, ElementName=page, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBlock FontSize="46" Text="{Binding SliderValue, ElementName=page}" />

<!-- works -->
<TextBlock FontSize="46" Text="{Binding Value, ElementName=myControl}" />
```

**The custom `Slider`**

As I said it directly inherts from `Slider`. Except this it is unchanged.

```
public sealed partial class MyUserControl : Slider
```

**Slider XAML**

(actually has a Style with a Template-Setter but even when empty the binding doesn't work)

```
<Slider
    x:Class="App1.MyUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="40"
    d:DesignWidth="200">
</Slider>
```

I also tried using a `DependencyProperty` instead of `PropertyChanged`-Event but it didn't help too.

Comment: Any binding errors in the output window?

Comment: You have set `x:Name="page"` on the Page?

Comment: no errors in output window, and I do have set the `x:Name="page"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Windows 10 UWP app right ?
In that case, if you want to bind to a property on the page you need to use the x:Bind notation, which uses the page itself as a data context :

```
<local:MyUserControl x:Name="myControl" Value="{x:Bind SliderValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```